# How to call public function within the file in Java?

Tags: java, eclipse, call, eclipse-luna, public-method

I tried to change the picture in this code. I tried to call the public function, and able to load when I want to call them out. I wanted to know how to do this, so that way I can put them in the if statement, while loop, or case statement.

In this code, I called a public function:

> test chill = new chill();

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.imageio.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class test extends Component {

    BufferedImage img;
    BufferedImage img1;

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);
        g.drawImage(img1,0,0,null);
    }

    public test() {
       try {
           img = ImageIO.read(new File("smile.png"));
       } catch (IOException e) {
       }

    }
    public chill() {
       try {
           img1 = ImageIO.read(new File("chill.png"));
       } catch (IOException e) {
       }

    }
//img1= ImageIO.read(new File("chill.png"));

    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        if (img == null) {
             return new Dimension(100,100);
        } else {
           return new Dimension(img.getWidth(null), img.getHeight(null));
       }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame f = new JFrame("Load Image Sample");

        f.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter(){
                public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                    System.exit(0);
                }
            });

        test chill = new chill();

        f.add(new test());
        f.pack();
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

What did I do wrong in this? If you have a website that explains about it, please post it on here! Thanks a tons!

This program is something that I do for fun.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the class should start with a capital letter (by convention). Second

```
test chill = new chill();
```

should be

```
test chill = new test();
```

Because `chill` is the variable name, and `test` is the class. Also, that's a constructor (not a method). And, you can't have a `chill` constructor in `test` class.

```
// public chill() {
//   try {
//       img1 = ImageIO.read(new File("chill.png"));
//   } catch (IOException e) {
//   }
// }
```

You could have a `chill` method

```
public void chill() {
   try {
       img1 = ImageIO.read(new File("chill.png"));
   } catch (IOException e) {
   }
}
```

And then

```
new test().chill();
```

would work.